# How do you specify only one option on a filter, such as FILTER_INT

Tags: php, filter

I've seen trillions (okay, perhaps not trillions but certainly billions) of examples of using the various PHP filters with an array of options but I haven't seen how you specify just one option.

For example:

On the page at http://www.w3schools.com/php/filter_validate_int.asp it says:

> Note: When specifying options in an array. The options must be in an
> associative multidimensional array with the name "options". See
> example below Example
>
> ?php $var=300;
>
> $int_options = array("options"=> array("min_range"=>0,
> "max_range"=>256));
>
> var_dump(filter_var($var, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT, $int_options)); ?>

On the page at http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_filter_var.asp there is:

> options   Optional. Specifies an associative array of flags/options or
> **a single flag/option**. Check each filter for possible options and flags

So - how do you specify only one option?

Say you wanted to check an integer and only specify the maximum value allowed. How do you code the filter_var option?

```
filter_var($var, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT, ????????)
```

What would you code in place of the ????????? to specify a maximum allowed value?

Is there a way to do it or do you always have to create, and pass, an associative array even if you use only one option?

Answer (score 2):

1. [Don't use w3schools for anything](http://w3fools.com/)
2. Use [php.net](http://php.net) for your PHP reference
3. If you did #1 and #2 you would see [that third parameter is optional and may be excluded](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php). If you wish to have only one option then you simply pass it only one option in the array:

   $int_options = array("options"=> array("max_range"=>256));